# Status bar icons color in vertical Multi-window Mode if the app window is in the second position

Tags: android, fullscreen, multi-window, split-screen

When in multi-window mode if the app window is in the second position, status bar icons color change their tint from white to black from time to time (if you rotate the phone) on Android 10 Lineage OS. There's no such bug on Samsung Stock running Android 9. It looks like android randomly gives priority to color scheme of the app in the first position.

Correct behavior:
[image: correct behavior]

Incorrect behavior:
[image: incorrect behavior]

styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Full source code is available at https://github.com/alecpetrosky/Android-Immerse-Demo

Answer (score 0):

It seems that rotation also makes Android to redraw status bar. Setting automatic recreation of Activity on configuration changes solved the problem.